# Numerical error in Mathieu functions

Tags: numerics, special-functions, precision-and-accuracy

Consider the [`MathieuCharacteristicA`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MathieuCharacteristicA.html) function, which is a piecewise function according to the documentation. The discontinuity happens at integer number.

```
With[{V0 = -1}, 
 Plot[MathieuCharacteristicA[κ, V0], {κ, -2.5, 2.5}]]
```

[image]

Consider the point approaching k=2 from the left side , and plot the Mathieu funtions near that point.

```
ParallelTable[
 Plot[Evaluate@
   With[{V0 = -1, κ = 2 - ϵ}, 
    Re@MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[κ, V0], V0, 
      z]], {z, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
  ImageSize -> Medium], {ϵ, {10^-8, 15/10*10^-8, 18/10*10^-8,
    2*10^-8}}]
```

[image]

We see that from points k=2-10^-8 , k=2-1.5*10^-8 to points k=1.8*^-8, k=2*^-8, there are big discontinouity. **Why does this big discontinuity happen in the Mathieu function**, even we are still away from the piecewise point? **Which result is correct?**

Moreover, as I increase the working precision, the results changes. Which results should I trust?

```
ParallelTable[
 Plot[Evaluate@
   With[{V0 = -1, κ = 2 - ϵ}, 
    Re@MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[κ, V0], V0, 
      z]], {z, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 50], {ϵ, {10^-8, 15/10*10^-8, 
   18/10*10^-8, 2*10^-8}}]
```

[image]

**Update:**

More strange behavior

```
NLimit[
 Re@MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[κ, -1], -1, 
   0], κ -> 2, Direction -> 1, WorkingPrecision -> 100]
(*
 0.000026560352729499428275267693547091828644960849846890155742135607985075453865741662994877041
*)


N[
 Table[Re@MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[2 - ϵ, -1], -1, 
    0], {ϵ, {10^-6, 10^-8, 10^-10, 10^-20, 10^-40, 10^-60, 
    10^-100}}], 100]
(* \
{9.375519741470728355592491183508603286638427801561870220416306315833951776806837902179623867179198570*10^-6, 
 9.375519742493871990285719573456924995106820123921565403331967009687923231481580841077469030562191305*10^-8, 
 9.375519742493974304649207591451232553957148872416907065490732452953108780592926489536671069329119067*10^-10, 
 9.375519742493974314881667185336397875216528878100913700967589255793432748631135267810942389900367393*10^-20, 
 9.375519654864253585910474819580416042344587293945440367769556457939085038181962308922619162634748808*10^-40,
1.114388591781733115021002428520876171768008184684161143978162399223107768160400228809114697590700165,
1.114388591781733115021002428520876171768008184684161143978162399223107768160400228809114697590700165} *)
```

What's the correct limit for k->2 ?

Comment: Mathematica [doesn't like Mathieu functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7798435/559318)

Comment: Definitely trust the one done with `WorkingPrecision` other than the default, which is `MachinePrecision`. In other words, precision tracking is **off by default** for `Plot`. This is a very bad thing for numerically sensitive functions such as the Mathieu functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we compare `N` on the exact values with the `MachinePrecision` values, we see that the second two graphs (of the first quartet) look correct and the first two are wrong.

```
Block[{z = 0},
 Table[With[{V0 = -1, κ = 2 - ϵ}, 
   Re@MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[κ, V0], V0, z]], {ϵ, {15/10*10^-8, 18/10*10^-8}}]
 ]
N[%, 6]
(*
{MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[399999997/200000000, -1], -1, 0], 
 MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[999999991/500000000, -1], -1, 0]}

{1.4063279613740616126811177594156`6.*^-7, 1.6875935536488557009743434482017`6.*^-7} 
*)

Block[{z = 0.},
 Table[With[{V0 = -1, κ = 2 - ϵ}, 
   Re@MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[κ, V0], V0, z]], {ϵ, {15/10*10^-8, 18/10*10^-8}}]
 ]
(*
{1.11439, 1.7027*10^-7}
*)
```

As the OP showed, this can be seen in the plots, if the `WorkingPrecision` is set high enough.  Clearly, one should trust the second quartet of plots if one is going to trust *Mathematica* at all.  `N[expr, n]` will report the answer with a precision that is supposed to be correct.

---

*Edit*

As [@acl](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/16/acl) has observed Mathieu functions are difficult functions numerically.  I would expect it to be even more difficult near a singular point of `MathieuCharacteristicA[κ, -1]`, where a little round-off error causes a discontinuous jump.

The following seem entirely consistent with the left-hand limit being zero, which is at the same time not inconsistent with the OP's evaluation of `NLimit`.

```
N@Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 500},
  NLimit[Re@MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[κ, -1], -1, 0],
    κ -> 2, Direction -> 1, WorkingPrecision -> 300, Terms -> 50]
  ]

N[Re@MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[2, -1], -1, 0], 10]

N@Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 500},
  NLimit[Re@MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[κ, -1], -1, 0],
    κ -> 2, Direction -> -1, WorkingPrecision -> 300, Terms -> 50]
  ]
(*
-1.49047*10^-45
0.8157268391
1.15361
*)
```

The inconsistencies observed by the OP seem to be due to round-off error.  I suppose one complaint is that *Mathematica* issues no warnings in evaluating the OP's examples, especially the ones involving `N` applied to an exact value.

Comment: Why does this big discontinuity happen in the Mathieu function, even we are still away from the piecewise point? You think Mathematica just got wrong?

Comment: @xslittlegrass Round-off error, no?  (Perhaps I should point it out explicitly?)

Comment: I'm not convinced it's simply the round-off error, see my updates.

Comment: @xslittlegrass Try `Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 500}, N[Table[Re@MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[2 - \[Epsilon], -1], -1, 0], {\[Epsilon], {10^-6, 10^-8, 10^-10, 10^-20, 10^-40, 10^-60, 10^-100}}], 300]]` (I wouldn't think 100 digits was enough for `2 - 10^-100`, which requires 101 digits just for itself.)

Comment: What about the disagreement to NLimit?

Comment: @xslittlegrass What calculations does `NLimit` actually do?

Comment: [NLimit](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/NumericalCalculus/ref/NLimit.html) "numerically finds the limiting value of expr as z approaches Subscript[z, 0]."

Comment: @xslittlegrass Yes, but **how**?  What calculations does it do? You need to know that in order to understand what's going on.

Comment: Sorry I still don't get you. But I see you use Terms options. But if you increase upto 100 terms, you get inconsistent result again. `N@Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 500}, 
  NLimit[Re@
    MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[\[Kappa], -1], -1, 0], \[Kappa] ->
     2, Direction -> 1, WorkingPrecision -> 300, Terms -> 100]] (*1.11439*)`

Comment: @xslittlegrass  What terms did `NLimit` add?  If they were closer to `κ = 2`, then you will have to increase the precision more to avoid the round-off error.  In other words, the closer to the singularity at `2` you push the calculation, the greater the precision you will need to get an accurate result.

Comment: OK, I start to see your point. Thanks for the help :)