# Why does N[Re@f] give complex result?

Tags: special-functions, complex, precision-and-accuracy, numerical-value

Consider this code:

```
BlochΚ[κ_, V0_, z_] := 
 MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[κ, 2 V0], 2 V0,  z/2] + 
  Sign[κ] I MathieuS[MathieuCharacteristicB[κ, 2 V0], 
    2 V0, z/2]

Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 500, ϵ = 10^-10}, N[Re@BlochΚ[-2 + ϵ, -1, -10]]]
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 1000, ϵ = 10^-20}, N[Re@BlochΚ[-2 + ϵ, -1, -10]]]
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 500, ϵ = 10^-10}, N[Re@BlochΚ[-2 + ϵ, -1, -10]]]
```

On a fresh kernel I get

```
(*
-0.484175
-0.993753
-1.38778*10^-16+6.17104*10^-9 I
*)
```

Why I get complex number at the third time even I used `Re` explicitly? And why the results are different for the first and third time? Did I made a stupid mistake or what?

Comment: Maybe related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798435/mathematica-evaluates-expression-once-then-returns-the-expression-unevaluated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** I think this is a numeric precision problem rather than a matter of the behavior of `Re`.
I don't know if I should leave my original answer below for reference or remove it.

Consider:

```
expr = MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[-(19999999999/10000000000), -2], -2, 5];

N[expr]
N[expr, 15]
SetPrecision[expr, 15]
```

> ```
> -9.85323*10^-16 + 3.39211*10^-8 I
>
> -0.484175231115992
>
> -0.4841752311160
> ```

Only the machine precision calculation returns a complex value.  I believe that puts this problem in the same class as:

- [Complex result for Real vectors in VectorAngle](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57377/121)

Sorry for the earlier misdirection.

Note: I believe `$MaxExtraPrecision` has no effect upon a machine precision calculations.

---

#### Old, misleading answer

Intending to further illuminate Junho Lee's answer we may consider how `Re` handles symbolic expressions:

```
Re[a + b I]
```

> ```
> -Im[b] + Re[a]
> ```

It performs this replacement whether or not `a` and `b` have a numeric equivalent.  Therefore:

```
Re[
  MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[-(19999999999/10000000000), -2], -2, 5] + 
   I MathieuS[MathieuCharacteristicB[-(19999999999/10000000000), -2], -2, 5]
]
```

Becomes:

```
Re[MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[-(19999999999/10000000000), -2], -2, 5]] - 
 Im[MathieuS[MathieuCharacteristicB[-(19999999999/10000000000), -2], -2, 5]]
```

And:

```
Re[MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[-(19999999999/10000000000), -2], -2, 5]]
```

> ```
> MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[-(19999999999/10000000000), -2], -2, 5]
> ```

```
Im[MathieuS[MathieuCharacteristicB[-(19999999999/10000000000), -2], -2, 5]]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

In some manner `Re` did its job, nevertheless this symbolic expression has a complex numeric value.

If you want a function that operates only on explicit numbers you might use:

```
re[x_?NumberQ] := Re[x]
```

Now `re` will remain unevaluated until its argument is expressly a number:

```
re[Pi + 4 I]
```

> ```
> re[4 I + π]
> ```

However `N` goes inside as `re` does not have [`NHoldFirst`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NHoldFirst.html) etc. therefore:

```
re[Pi + 4 I] // N
```

> ```
> 3.14159
> ```

Comment: Did `Re` do its job wrong? If that's true then it's really scary for me since I used a lot of Mathematica's analytical simplification in my work. I'm wondering whether `Re` did it correctly but `N` did it wrong instead. For example `N[MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[-(19999999999/10000000000), -2], -2,
   5], 10]` give me a real number. Maybe this is another expression of [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58297/1364). Mathieu functions have driven me crazy :)

Comment: @xslittlegrass I am not familiar with these functions (in or out of *Mathematica*) and I did not check for that, but it seems likely that this is a numeric precision problem after all, which largely invalidates my answer.

Answer (score 8):

I think your problems are made by order of appling `Re` and `N`. `Re@Bloch` is not yet a state before the computation. So you have to apply the computation by  `Re@N`order.

```
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 500, ϵ = 10^-10}, Re@N@BlochΚ[-2 + ϵ, -1, -10]]
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 1000, ϵ = 10^-20}, Re@N@BlochΚ[-2 + ϵ, -1, -10]]
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 500, ϵ = 10^-10}, Re@N@BlochΚ[-2 + ϵ, -1, -10]]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

```
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 500, ϵ = 10^-10}, Re@BlochΚ[-2 + ϵ, -1, -10]]
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 1000, ϵ = 10^-20}, Re@BlochΚ[-2 + ϵ, -1, -10]]
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 500, ϵ = 10^-10}, Re@BlochΚ[-2 + ϵ, -1, -10]]
```

> [image: Blockquote]