# NIntegral first "hit" is not equal to second "hit"

Tags: numerical-integration, bugs, special-functions, version-10, mac-os-x

Consider the following code:

```
r = 30; a = 95/100; q = (r Sqrt[1 - a^2]/a)^2/4; m = 4;
ce[m_, q_, x_] := 
  MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[m, q], q, x];
1/Pi NIntegrate[Cos[x] Sin[r /a Cos[x]] ce[m, q, x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"]
```

When I "hit" the `shift+enter` the first time, the result is:`-0.0426046`; the second "hit" gives `-0.0673913`. None of them is equal to the analytical result: `-0.055116186075968306`.

Note that to reproduce the bizarre behavior,  **you need change `m` to other integers and then change back to `4`.** If you make a fresh startup of Mathematica, it will give the right results no matter how many times you "hit". However, as long as you change `m` to other values and then change back, it will have the problem I described.

When $m\neq 4$, the numerical integration gives the right results.

MM version: 10.4.1.0

osx:10.11.6 EI Capitan

I also tried it on Linux with version 10.4.1, same problem.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in V10.0.1.

Comment: I get `-0.0551162` using "11.1.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 18, 2017)".  Can you give your precise version number and OS?

Comment: It has been noted several times on this site that Mathieu functions are problematic.  Here is the same problem with reevaluating them: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58335/why-does-nref-give-complex-result

Comment: Also can't reproduce the problem on "11.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 21, 2016)"

Comment: @march Have you changed `m` back and forth ?

Comment: @mikado need to change back and forth.

Comment: @yohbs need to change back and forth.

Comment: In v9.0.1 `-0.0551162` is returned instantly for the first time, but if I change `m` back and forth and retry, the calculation never finishes then.

Comment: In V11.1.1 (Mac) I can get three answers, first `-0.0551162`; then change `m`, evaluate, change back to `m =4` and get `-0.0426046`; finally `ClearSystemCache[]` and get `-0.0615031`. If I change `m` back and forth again, I get `-0.0426046`. And whenever I evaluate `ClearSystemCache[]`, I get `-0.0615031`.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/q/7798435/1004168 known bug persisting at least 6 years

Comment: Okay: I change `m` back and forth, and just like @MichaelE2, got the numbers changing.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you are not doing numerical calculations right. Your variables must be floats, nut integers which can be achieved by placing a dot in front of your values (e.g. `a = 90/100` becomes `a = 90./100.`). This would fix your problem, however, there are two other issues with your coding style: function arguments have the same name as your assigned variables, and you do not clear your variables before rerunning your notebook. All three have been fixed in the following cell:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
r = 30.;
a = 95./100.;
q = (r Sqrt[1 - a^2]/a)^2/4;
m = 4;
ce[mm_, qq_, xx_] := MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[mm, qq], qq, xx];

1/Pi NIntegrate[Cos[x] Sin[r/a Cos[x]] ce[m, q, x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Method -> "GaussKronrodRu
```

Comment: It's a nice observation that using `Real` numbers for the `q` parameter in `MathieuCharacteristicA` is a workaround (+1), but the assertion "Your variables must be floats" runs counter to the design of *Mathematica* and the documentation for `MathieuCharacteristicA`.

Comment: @MichaelE2, I'm not sure if it actually runs counter to the design of *Mathematica*. *Mathematica* is a programming language that contains symbolic calculations as well as numerical calculations. For numerical calculations, one should use float precision and for symbolic, one is free to choose other forms.