# Mathematica doesn't evaluate MathieuC function for large arguments

Tags: numerical-integration, evaluation, special-functions, precision-and-accuracy

Various `MathieuC` problems identified here have been reported as CASE:3698818.

I need to calculate some numeric integrations of the periodic Mathieu's Functions. So I used NIntegrate and it works well as long as the arguments of the function are not too large.
Whenever I try to do the calculation with a large argument, Mathematica leaves the function unevaluated and I get the "The integrand has evaluated to non-numerical values" error.

I noticed that when I round off the arguments, or use Rationalize to get a rational approximation of them, it does evaluate the function, but the problem with that is that the functions are very sensitive to argument changes - as soon as I round off the argument the function stops being periodic and becomes exponentially growing - which is definitely not what I'm looking for. I tried increasing the precision of the approximation, and it wasn't precise enough when Mathematica stopped evaluating the function again.

So what I need is to keep the precision but make Mathematica evaluate the function. (The built-in function Evaluate doesn't work either)

Is there a way to do that?

Here are some code lines for example:

```
    b = 0.49
    q = q /. FindRoot[-2 q b == MathieuCharacteristicA[6, q], {q, 1000}]
    q2 = q /. FindRoot[-2 q b == MathieuCharacteristicA[8, q], {q, 1000}]
    NIntegrate[MathieuC[-2 q b, q, x]*MathieuC[-2 q2 b, q2, x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
    Plot[Evaluate[{Re[#], Im[#]} &@MathieuC[-2 q2 b, q2, x]], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Blue, Dashed}}]
```

Thanks!

Comment: I believe this is the cause of the problem: `MathieuC[-2 q b, q, x]` doesn't seem to evaluate at any `x`.

Comment: Trouble with Mathieu functions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7798435, [(58297)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58297), [(81395)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/81395), [(83032)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83032).

Comment: @MichaelE2 All the linked issues still persist in v11 on my machine.  Can you confirm?

Comment: @QuantumDot No, I'm using 10.4.1.

Comment: @MichaelE2  Running the first block of your code with version 11.0, I do not obtain the same results that you (and I) obtain with version 10.4.1.

Comment: @MichaelE2  Values returned by `MathieuC[]` sometimes also depend in a repeatable manner on earlier calls to this function.  For `q` as defined in the question, `MathieuC[-2 q b, q, 1.1]` returns unevaluated, but `MathieuC[1, 1, 1.1]; MathieuC[-2 q b, q, 1.1]` returns a plausible but incorrect answer.  This is true for both 10.4.1 and 11.0.

Comment: @bbgodfrey That's sound familiar.  There's either a Q&A or it was in chat. I just don't use them enough, I guess, to keep it all in mind.  I mainly remember that they can be a PIA, numerically.

Answer (score 6):

It wasn't real clear to me exactly what the OP did about precision, but code below looks like it might be working.  You seem to need fairly high precision for all arguments.

```
b = 0.49`100;
q1 = q /. 
  FindRoot[-2 q b == MathieuCharacteristicA[6, q], {q, 1000}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 100]
q2 = q /. 
  FindRoot[-2 q b == MathieuCharacteristicA[8, q], {q, 1000}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 100]
(*
605.789297872353700695280254027183815298851997479216300967816087036777\
2075840329756326461722267299774

1036.13835973661722165073772712372558794514088740162366560455284235128\
4742499772811507801258473196255
*)

NIntegrate[
 MathieuC[-2 q1 b, q1, x]*MathieuC[-2 q2 b, q2, x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PrecisionGoal -> 8, WorkingPrecision -> 100]
(*
1.43071586725038018235424085351766966962166226308387215510919976577346\
8232618999353484020990207944397
*)

data = Table[MathieuC[-2 q1 b, q1, x]*MathieuC[-2 q2 b, q2, x], {x, 0, 2 Pi, 2*Pi/1000}];
plot = ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> All, DataRange -> {0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To use `Plot` instead of `ListLinePlot`, set `WorkingPrecision -> 100`.  One should also limit `MaxRecursion` because computation of the Mathieu functions at high precision is slow.  The setting `MaxRecursion -> 2` reduced the time by about `1/10` of the default setting, from `86` sec. to about `8.7`. (`PlotPoints -> 100` was used to capture all the oscillations.)

```
Plot[MathieuC[-2 q1 b, q1, x]*MathieuC[-2 q2 b, q2, x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
  PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 2,   (* for speed *)
  WorkingPrecision -> 100, PlotRange -> All] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

At least we can show that the graph and the integral are consistent: We construct a polygon from the graph:

```
Graphics@Cases[plot, 
  Line[p_] :> Polygon@Reverse@Join[p, {{2 Pi, -2}, {0, -2}}], 
  Infinity]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then we can take the area of the polygon and subtract the area of the rectangle below the x-axis and approximate the integral.  (To get the area the edge of the polygon must trace the boundary counterclockwise; hence the `Reverse[]`.)

```
Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[];

Cases[plot, 
  Line[p_] :> PolygonArea@Reverse@Join[p, {{2 Pi, -2}, {0, -2}}], 
  Infinity] - 4 Pi
(*  {1.430715867250397`}   *)
```

So the approximation agrees with the integral to 14 digits, which is pretty good.

Caveat: Somehow using the built-in `Area` function on the polygon crashes my kernel (V10.4.1). Hence I used the method from [How do I calculate the area of a polygon given its coordinates?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31241/how-do-i-calculate-the-area-of-a-polygon-given-its-coordinates/31243#31243).

---

*Normalization (response to comment)*

@bbgodfrey reports in a comment & his answer a difference between V10.4.1 and V11.   The ratio between the integrals have a suspiciously familiar value:

```
2.023337783/1.43071586725
(*  1.41421  *)
```

If I check [DLMF 28.2.30](http://dlmf.nist.gov/28.2#E30), I see in V10.4.1, the normalization is satisfied:

```
NIntegrate[MathieuC[-2 q1 b, q1, x]^2, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PrecisionGoal -> 8, WorkingPrecision -> 100]
(*  3.14159265358979323846...  *)

NIntegrate[MathieuC[-2 q2 b, q2, x]^2, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PrecisionGoal -> 8, WorkingPrecision -> 100]
(*  3.141592653589793238462...  *)
```

The documentation page [`MathieuC`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MathieuC.html) does not indicate an update since V3.0.

Comment: Thanks!
This does seem to work for b=0.49 as I originally defined.
The problem is that in my project I also need to work with values like b=0.99, for which the precision just doesn't seem to be enough (I tried up to WorkingPrecision=10,000) or maybe I am getting something wrong... Do you have an idea how to deal with that?

Comment: @Assaf Maybe you can use the diff. eq. like Ruslan did in [his question here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83032/is-mathieuc-for-moderately-large-imaginary-arguments-broken) and bbgodfrey did his answer to this question?  This shows how sensitive the built-in `MathieuC` is to slight errors: `Table[MathieuC[-2 q2 b, q, 11/10.`100], {q, q2 - 10^-20, q2 + 10^-20, 10^-20}]` (use with the 100-digit parameters in my answer). Actually, though, if I change `b` to ``b = 0.99`100`` in my code above, the computations go through and seem reasonable (i.e. consistent). I'm using V10.4.1.

Comment: I will try using the diff eq. I am guessing when you changed to b=0.99 you got negative values for q. for them it works, but there are also positive values (they are very large, so the start point for FindRoot should be about 10^7 to find them), and when I try it with them it fails - I get non-periodic functions that grow exponentially. I should have mentioned that earlier.

Comment: @Assaf Yes, I got negative -- didn't think about that.  Oh well...Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

It also is possible to solve this problem from first principles, obtaining the symmetric Mathieu functions by solving Mathieu's equation.

```
s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{c''[x] - 2 q (49/100 + Cos[2 x]) c[x] == 0, c[0] == 1, 
    c'[0] == 0}, c, {x, 0, Pi}, {q}, WorkingPrecision -> 60, MaxSteps -> 50000];

q1 = q /. FindRoot[s[q][Pi] == 1, {q, 606}, WorkingPrecision -> 60]
norm1 = Sqrt[2 NIntegrate[(s[q1][x])^2, {x, 0, Pi}, WorkingPrecision -> 60]/Pi];
Plot[s[q1][x]/norm1, {x, 0, Pi}]
(* 605.789297872353700695280254027186743825904841833249641547632 *)
```

[image]

```
q2 = q /. FindRoot[s[q][Pi] == 1, {q, 1036}, WorkingPrecision -> 60]
norm2 = Sqrt[2 NIntegrate[(s[q2][x])^2, {x, 0, Pi}, WorkingPrecision -> 60]/Pi];
Plot[s[q2][x]/norm2, {x, 0, Pi}]

(* 1036.13835973661722165073772712373596893094034394911310331033 *)
```

[image]

```
2 NIntegrate[s[q1][x] s[q2][x], {x, 0, Pi}, WorkingPrecision -> 60]/(norm1 norm2)

(* 1.43127146207803138094684879314159579110898733451406636889128 *)
```

Results are about the same with `WorkingPrecision -> 30`.

Although values of `q1` and `q2` obtained here agree with those in the answer by [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) to of order `10^-29`, the final integral differs by of order 0.1% between the two solutions.  To attempt to understand this difference, I ran the first block of Michael E2's code on version 10.4.1 and obtained his final integral.  However, running his code on version 11.0 produced a final integral of `2.023337783...`!  The normalization of `MathieuC[-2 q1 b, q1, x]` differs substantially between the two versions.  As noted in the comments attached to the original question, Mathematica's implementation of `MathieuC` is not reliable.

Comment: I looked into this and wondered if MathieuC was discontinuous at the value of q considered.